# Angular matdatepicker wrong date printed

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material-7, formatdatetime

I'm using a `matDatePicker` this way:

```
 <mat-form-field class="col">
    <input #pickerDal matInput [matDatepicker]="pickerDal" placeholder="Dal" 
    (dateChange)="fromDate('change', $event)" formControlName="formDataDal">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerDal"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #pickerDal></mat-datepicker> 
  </mat-form-field>
```

and in my .ts I have declared:

```
formDataDal: new FormControl()
```

it was working correctly until I've decided to add a default display value in the date picker. What I did was adding `[(ngModel)]="dal_default"` inside `input` tag, and in .ts file and initializing `dal_default` :

```
this.dal_default = new Date();
```

Now if I try to print the value of the Date using the formControlName or this `dal_default` variable, I get a strange format string. In particular, if I print the default date displayed, it is correctly printed as date, but then if I change the date I get a string (I believe it represents the milliseconds?). FOr example, the following one is the one I get from Date 12/12/2018:

```
1543618800000
```

The only other thing I did was change the date format inside `app.module.ts` to have Dates in DD/MM/YYYY format:

```
import { DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material';
import { MomentDateModule, MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';


export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MM YYYY',
  },
};
```

and inside providers:

```
 { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'it' }, 
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS }
```

The matdatepicker correctly shows the date in the format I want. I do not believe this is the problem, but can't be 100% sure.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you create stackblitz example for this, it will be better to understand what you are doing, and it will be easier for people to help you?